# Required fields

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm doing a migration from csv to Drupal 8 and I'm not sure how to handle the required fields.

My content type "Department" has 8 required fields, should I use the plugin "skip_on_empty" in every migration field? There is a simpler way to do this?

[image]

[image]

The point is prevent empty required fields. Thanks all.

Comment: Well, having the data is better than not having the data. Any reason you are not stubbing? That would put a placeholder value in until the actual record is migrated.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a business decision and not a Drupal related question. You have three solutions

1. Bring in the data as is and end up with a corrupted database
2. Skip rows that do not answer to your requirements
3. Give default values to the required fields